# PagerSlidingTabStrip cannot help me change tab Indicator color [Android]

Tags: android, colors, tabs

I have followed the example

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

by extracting the resources xml attributes and Pager class to implement into my class such that the tab indicator color is not pale blue but other colors by setting SetIndicator

When it comes tto the implementation, it seems that I cannot change the color as wished. Would you please tell me how to import the library project or other ways such that I can change the tab indicator color?

The below is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs ;
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip strip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Initilization

        strip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();     
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);     
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        
        strip.setIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#00ffbf"));
    //  strip.setShouldExpand(true);
        //strip.setIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#00ffbf"));
    //  strip.setViewPager(viewPager);


        // Adding Tabs
        tabs = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options);

        for (String tab_name : tabs) {


            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                //actionBar.getTabAt(position).getCustomView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ffbf"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        //  tab.set
        //  

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //      mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //      mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);     
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        /*  if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }*/
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        /*      case R.id.action_profile:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class));
            return true;*/

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseColor()` supports two formats: `#RRGGBB` and `#AARRGGBB`, Have you tried with the alpha format?:

```
strip.setIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#ff00ffbf"));
```

If that doesn't work, you can try changing the default color directly from the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` class:

```
private int indicatorColor = 0xFF00FFBF;
```

Comment: Then, write that in the title of your question and not "tab Indicator color". Use the setUnderlineColor() method for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,in easy way

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />
```